# Meaning of "you should be all set up to do so."

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

I read the git document here:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started

What is the meaning of "all set up" in the sentence below:

> you should be all set up to do so.

Does this sentence mean "You should ready to do so"?

Comment: i think it means that you should be prepared to do so

Comment: Yes, "be prepared" is better than "ready".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence means that after working through the chapter you should have the software installed and the knowledge to let you use it correctly.

In this context "all set up" implies you will have everything you need ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Set up or setup I think refers to some form of work that needed to be done beforehand. Once its done, you all set up to do so, whatever "so" might mean.

Setup is a commonly used computer term but not all English dictionaries accept it and rather use set up.

The meaning of the whole sentence is:

> "you should make a plan to do so."
>
> or:
>
> "you should be prepared to do so."

Reference:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159236/to-set-up-for-to-arrange-prepare-or-to-organize-in-colloquial-ame

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21507/is-the-use-of-all-set-exclusive-to-certain-regions

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117599/setup-or-set-up

Comment: And what is the meaning of the whole sentence?

Answer (score 0):

It simply means, "everything is inclusive in the upcoming chapters or lessons to make you prepare relatively for what you are going to learn ahead".